# "New Horizons' capabilities augmented by uploading new observing and onboard data-reduction software." How? What augmentations are begin considered?

Tags: new-horizons, software, autonomy, kuiper-belt, extended-mission

A comment below [New Horizons current mission](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51680/12102) links to the Johns Hopkins University Applied Physics Laboratory page [2019 Onward](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/Mission/2019-Onward.php) which includes the following:

> It is possible that another flyby target can be found and reached with New Horizons' remaining fuel supply. And after that? **Another exciting possibility is that we can dramatically augment New Horizons' capabilities by uploading new observing and onboard data-reduction software once the spacecraft's flyby software is no longer needed. If NASA approves such a plan, New Horizons could survey the Kuiper Belt population in ways that no other mission or telescope on Earth or in Earth orbit can, and possibly even detect and hunt down its own next flyby target.**
>
> Future New Horizons extended missions, if funded by NASA, could explore even farther out. The spacecraft is on an escape trajectory from the Sun, traveling about three astronomical units per year. (An astronomical unit, or AU, is the average distance from Earth to the Sun, about 93 million miles or 149 million kilometers.) Moreover, New Horizons and its payload sensors are healthy and operating perfectly. The spacecraft has enough power and fuel to operate into the mid-2030s or longer, perhaps enough to reach the boundary of interstellar space.

**Question:** How can New Horizons' capabilities be augmented by uploading new observing and onboard data-reduction software. What capability augmentations are begin considered?

Potentially related and helpful in Astronomy SE:

- [Can New Horizons be used to measure the distance to Betelgeuse (despite its fickle photocenter)?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39427/7982)

Comment: companion question: [How much space could be freed up on New Horizons “once the spacecraft's flyby software is no longer needed”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51684/12102)